# Cookies don't update on some android browsers

Tags: php, android, cookies

I've developed a two-steps verification login which uses cookies to check if a device has already been verified or not: this cookie contains an unique id and a random password which changes on every access of the device.
To do that update, I use this php code

```
setcookie('nameofthecookie', '', time()-600,"/");
setcookie('nameofthecookie', $newcookiecontent, time()+2629743,"/");
```

Which works perfectly on most browsers, but it does not on some android ones: infact, using them, the cookie does not update.

**What I've tried to do:**

1. Only creating a cookie using

   setcookie('nameofthecookie', $newcookiecontent, time()+2629743,"/");

   and *it works*;
2. Only deleting a cookie using

   setcookie('nameofthecookie', '', time()-600,"/");

   and *it works*.

Anyone could suggest me a solution?

Comment: don't use "near" relative times to expire a cookie. You're depending on the user's clock being relatively accurate. Always use a "distant" time, e.g. time = 1 (Jan 1/1970 00:00:01am). If anyone's clock is SO far out that they're back beyond the 70s, then they deserve to not have things working properly

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm updating my code like you suggested. So the correct code is setcookie('nameofthecookie', '', time(1),"/");
 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code leads to the following header which is sent to the client:

```
Set-Cookie nameofthecookie=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/ 
           nameofthecookie=somevalue; expires=Sat, 24-May-2014 22:11:13 GMT; Max-Age=2629743; path=/
```

Based on the [RFC for HTTP Cookies](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (page 9), it is not defined which one of the cookies the browser will choose if the path is the same:

> If multiple cookies satisfy the criteria above, they are ordered in
>   the Cookie header such that those with more specific Path attributes
>   precede those with less specific.  Ordering with respect to other
>   attributes (e.g., Domain) is unspecified.

So maybe the Android Browser chooses the cookie with the emtpy value, and your desktop browser chooses the later one. The [Netscape specification for cookies](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) states that

> Instances of the same path and name will overwrite each other, with
>   the latest instance taking precedence. Instances of the same path but
>   different names will add additional mappings.

Actually, you do not need to reset the cookie to a blank value before setting a new value. Just remove the first line of your code.

See [this tutorial](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript) for more information about managing cookies with PHP.